# Android permission INTERNET

Tags: android, permissions

Sorry, my English is not very good

The other company said it must remove this permission, he said it was a weakness

If i can not use this right?

There are other ways? I have to use Internet

Comment: That permission should remain if the application has any network operations.

Comment: If you want to use the Internet on phone , you must be use the Internet permission. Why it was a weakness ?

Comment: They use "fortify" This tool scans!
https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/zh_TW/vulncat/java/privilege_management_android_network.html

Comment: it seems no other way. If you want to use the internet , you should add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`  in you `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app needs network connection, then there is no other way but granting the internet permission. I am using this in my many applications. I don't know how this is a weakness. See this [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I´m a bit late, but the vulnerability your talking about refers to a violation of the least privilege principle, it simply says that your application  should have the minimum amount of privilege possible, if you need the internet access privilege, the vulnerability is a false positive.
https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.configuration.java.privilege_management_unnecessary_permission